# InvalidOperationException while tryin to set reminders in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, reminders

Im trying to set reminders, and im stuck with this error "BNS Error: The action's start time has passed when trying to create/update the request."

Searchin the forum and googling din find me much answers for a similar error, this is how i have set the reminders, the exception is fired for (m_iSafe2>0) condition

```
            if (m_bSafeAlert)
            {
            if (m_iSafe1 > 0)
            {
                date = dtStart.AddDays(m_iSafe1);
                date = date.Date + time;
                noOfDays = m_iUnsafe1 - m_iSafe1;

                Reminder Safe1Reminder = new Reminder("Safe1")
                {
                    BeginTime = date,
                    Title = "Reminder",
                    Content = "Reminder 1",
                };
                ScheduledActionService.Add(Safe1Reminder);                    
            }

            if (m_iSafe2 > 0) // exception fired
            {
                date = dtStart.AddDays(m_iSafe2);
                date = date.Date + time;
                noOfDays = m_iAvgCycleTime - m_iSafe2;

                Reminder Safe2Reminder = new Reminder("Safe2")
                {
                    BeginTime = date,
                    Title = "Reminder",
                    Content = "Reminder2",
                };
                ScheduledActionService.Add(Safe2Reminder);
            }
```

Where am i goin wrong?

Alfah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to create reminder with scheduled time that has been already passed

Comment: so the first reminder is not set you mean? or the second? I checked the dates, i have correctly set them

Comment: Add `Debug.WriteLine("Now: " + DateTime.Now + " Scheduled to: " + date)` to both reminders. Just for my curiosity

Comment: And what output on `Debug` console? :)   Add to `Safe2Reminder` too

Comment: One more question, can we delete all reminders in one go rather than havin to search for each and remove?

Comment: With `GetActions<Reminder>` you can get `Enumerable` of all registered `Reminders`. Then you can remove them one-by-one. I don't see easier way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh220821(v=vs.92).aspx